# Do I need to ground my off-grid house inverter?

Tags: electrical, grounding, inverter

I'm building a battery box for my off-grid house, consisting of a 155AH AGM sealed battery, Krieger 1100-watt inverter and a Samlex SEC-1230UL 30A battery charger for using my generator to charge the battery. I'll also have two cigarette lighters and a small water pump attached to the battery.

Everything will have its own appropriate inline fuse and everything will be connected directly to the battery terminals. Maybe not the most proper way to do things but with how simple it is I think it's fairly reasonable to connect everything directly.

My question is, do I need to ground any of this?

It's all just going to be in a battery box by my desk, there's no holes in the floor currently. It would be a fairly large hassle to run a ground line and I'm not sure if I know how or what the purpose of it is. The inverter says to run a ground wire to the chassis, but it's more of an inverter for a vehicle.

Any advice?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/492653/152903

Comment: Is this inverter feeding a panel (breaker box, loadcenter) of some sort or another?  Also, can you post a link to its installation manual?

Comment: No it's just a two plug-in inverter so that I can plug in my laptop and monitor, nothing more. Manual: https://www.kriegermfg.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/KR1100_1500_2000_MANUAL.pdf

Comment: I would suggest grounding and lightning protection for safety. Lightning protections requires a good earth ground.

Comment: 2 cigarettes lighters you have a serious problem and should quit! , sorry I know that was off topic but could not help it.